# SQL Server user best practice

Tags: sql-server, security

I have a login with Windows Authentication which is called domain\username. Now I want to map this login to my DB and the SSMS is proposing a user called domain\username as well.

I don't know if I have to map the domain login to the database user as **domain\username** or simply as **username**.
What is the best practice?
THANKS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to map him as domain\username, another way would be to have domain groups and then all you need to do is add users to it

Comment: +1 for the domain group - that way it can be managed externally.